# Raspberry Pi - Resolution Issues

Tags: debian, resolution, raspberry-pi, fullscreen, xrandr

**Background of Problems**

I currently have a Raspberry Pi hooked up to a [touchscreen LCD panel](https://www.chalk-elec.com/?page_id=1280#!/15-6-HDMI-interface-LCD-refurbished-15/p/88115679/category=0) running [FullPageOS](https://github.com/guysoft/FullPageOS) which basically is Debian that starts up with Chromium at full screen to a desired webpage.  I have two problems though:

1. Webpage won't extend fully:

[image]

This problem extends to the console (not just chromium):

[image]

If I type enough in the console to where I am further down the page than a full screen, I am typing off screen.

2. Touch screen is off

[image]

The point that I touch is not where the mouse goes. This error is worse the further away from the top left of the screen I am at. For example if I touch the upper left, the mouse pretty much matches.

**Problem Summary**

This has lead me to believe that the resolution is off since things aren't fitting on the screen correctly. Native resolution according to the website that I bought it from is `1366x768` but it appears my Raspberry Pi is running at `1280x800` instead.

**What I have tried**

I have tried for months to fix this problem.

- I have fully reinstalled the OS which yields the same results.
- I have tried to change the resolution in the console:
- `DISPLAY=:0.0 randr` lists the screen as `HDMI-1` with the following:

[image]

- Since it only lists the one resolution to choose from, I have tried to manually add a new resolution as well but get the error `Configure crtc 0 failed`. See below:

[image]

**Question**

So I am at a loss for what I can try. Is the resolution my problem like I thought it was? If so, how do I fix it since what I tried hasn't worked?

**Config.txt**

```
 # For more options and information see
 # http://rpf.io/configtxt
 # Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

 # uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
 #hdmi_safe=1

 # uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
 # and your display can output without overscan
 #disable_overscan=1

 # uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
 # goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
 #overscan_left=16
 #overscan_right=16
 #overscan_top=16
 #overscan_bottom=16

 # uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
 # overscan.
 #framebuffer_width=1366
 #framebuffer_height=768

 # uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
 #hdmi_force_hotplug=1

 # uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
 hdmi_group=2
 hdmi_mode=81
 hdmi_cvt=1366 768 60 3

 # uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
 # DMT (computer monitor) modes
 #hdmi_drive=2

 # uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
 # no display
 #config_hdmi_boost=4

 # uncomment for composite PAL
 #sdtv_mode=2

 #uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
 #arm_freq=800

  # Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
  #dtparam=i2c_arm=on
  #dtparam=i2s=on
  #dtparam=spi=on

 # Uncomment this to enable the lirc-rpi module
 #dtoverlay=lirc-rpi

 # Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

 # Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
 dtparam=audio=on
 # enable raspicam
 start_x=1
 #gpu_mem=128
 dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
```

Comment: Try in Config.txt to add `hdmi_cvt=1366 768 60 3`. ([link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md))

Comment: @harrymc I have added that line to my config.txt but still the same issue. I updated my question to what I have now with it in there. For what its worth, when I visit http://whatismyscreenresolution.net/ it states that the screen is 1280x800 still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So on my screen the touchscreen portioned was hard set to 1366 x 768 no matter what I tried to configure it to be differently. This is why there was a mismatch of where was touched vs where the mouse went.

My solution was to ditch FullPageOS and install the latest version of Raspbian. I saw that my resolution was not in the drop down from the GUI (Preferences > Raspberry Pi Configuration > Set Resolution) so I edited `/boot/config.txt` adding the lines:

```
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=81
```

I rebooted and my resolution and touchscreen problems went away!

This must mean something in the FullPageOS was preventing my changes in the config.txt. I hope this solution helps others in the future even if it won't be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to force the Raspberry Pi to boot in a pre-set resolution by editing /boot/config.txt

See https://elinux.org/RPiconfig#Video

In your case you could try to add the following lines:

```
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=81
```

And reboot.

hdmi_mode = 81 selects 1366 x 768 x 60Hz.

On the linked page you can find some alternatives, for example hdmi_mode = 86 selects 1366 x 768 with reduced blanking and hdmi_mode = 39 selects 1360 x 768.

Make sure you have a means to restore the original /boot/config.txt if you have any problems.

Comment: So I actually have that too. See my updated question as I have now included my config.txt